# A question regarding the common terms of two APs.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

What is the sum of first $50$ terms common to the $AP$ $15,19,23,\dots$ and the $AP$ $14,19,24,\dots$?
I know that:
The common terms start from $19$ and nothing else. I have tried this but I am facing a lot of difficulty. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

- $a_n=15+\color\red4n$
- $b_n=14+\color\green5n$

We know that:

- $LCM(\color\red4,\color\green5)=20$
- The first common element is $19$

Hence the AP of common elements is $c_n=19+20n$.

And the sum of the first $50$ elements is $50(c_{0}+c_{49})/2=25450$.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very good answer. ^_^

Comment: @LokeshSangewar: Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider that $(4\mathbf{Z}+15) \cap (5\mathbf{Z}+14)=20\mathbf{Z}+19$. Hence
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{49}20n+19=20\left(\sum_{i=0}^{49}n\right)+19\cdot 50=20\cdot \frac{49\cdot 50}{2}+19\cdot 50.
$$

Comment: How did u get that first expression?

Comment: Ok I got it by thinking a bit!

Comment: By the Chinese reminder theorem, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: But why did u take only the sum of first 19 terms? 
And is 19.20.11 the final answer?

Comment: Nope, read it now

Comment: Explain it in simple words please

Comment: Like u haven't used the mod concept anywhere so how?

Comment: "The mod concept"? The sum is for the first 50 terms, as you asked in the above.

Comment: That Chinese remainder theroem is something related to mod and thing right?

Comment: Well, it is something more general. However, for your exercise it is enough to see that the first airthmetic progression is (a subset of) the set of all integers $x$ such that $x\equiv 3\bmod{4}$.